# How is Zclassic's pszTimeStamp generated, and what does it mean?

Tags: zcash

How is `pszTimestamp` from Zclassic generated, and what does it mean ?

```
Zclassic860413afe207aa173afee4fcfa9166dc745651c754a41ea8f155646f5aa828ac
```

Any idea?

Same encryption is used in BTCP and Zcash.

Answer (score 2):

The derivation is given in [the Zclassic codebase](https://github.com/z-classic/zclassic/blob/master/src/chainparams.cpp#L74-L75):

```
from pyblake2 import blake2s
'Zclassic' + blake2s(b'No taxation without representation. BTC #437541 - 00000000000000000397f175a94dd3f530b957182eb2a9f7b79a44a94a5e0450').hexdigest()
```

The reason they generate it in this way is because Zcash generates its `pszTimestamp` [like so](https://github.com/zcash/zcash/blob/master/src/chainparams.cpp#L51-L52):

```
from pyblake2 import blake2s
'Zcash' + blake2s(b'The Economist 2016-10-29 Known unknown: Another crypto-currency is born. BTC#436254 0000000000000000044f321997f336d2908cf8c8d6893e88dbf067e2d949487d ETH#2521903 483039a6b6bd8bd05f0584f9a078d075e454925eb71c1f13eaff59b405a721bb DJIA close on 27 Oct 2016: 18,169.68').hexdigest()
```

And the reason Zcash generates it in this way is because there is a [consensus rule](https://github.com/zcash/zcash/blob/master/src/main.cpp#L1277-L1279) (inherited from [Bitcoin](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/consensus/tx_verify.cpp#L195-L196)) that limits the size of a coinbase `scriptSig` to a maximum of 100 bytes.